# htaccess and AddType/Addhandler

Tags: .htaccess

My main site script uses php4, and it works fine with the AddHandler. Since the server is configured or php5.3 by default I assume when adding another script to a subdirectory all i would have to do is use one of the following Addhandler/AddType below but, it does not work. When I added anyone of the 3 lines before the pages are sent to the browser as a download so it doesn't process the file for display at all. my htaccess is completely blank expect for the Addhandler. Also this is on a dedicated server.

```
AddType application/php5-script php html tpl 
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php .php4 .php3 .phtml .tpl .html
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php53 .php .php4 .php3 .phtml .tpl .html

    to explain better..
    1. www.site.com is run php4 (script req. it)
    2. www.site.com/newscript/ needs php5
    3. i put a .htaccess in the www.site.com/newscript/ folder with 
Addhandler for php5 but it doesn't work
```

Answer (score 1):

Am a bit confused by your question, do you mean you are running php 4 and 5 on the same server and want some parts of the site to run php4, some php5?

If it's a new server and you can't get the posted code to work have you tried

```
 AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .php4 .php3 .phtml .tpl .html
```

Comment: to explain better..
1. www.site.com is run php4 (script req. it)
2. www.site.com/newscript/ needs php5
3. i put a .htaccess in the www.site.com/newscript/ folder with Addhandler for php5 but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Server needs to be running latest PHP 5.3, you can downgrade with `.htaccess` to PHP 4 but if server is not running at least PHP 5.3 you can not make it do so with `.htaccess`. Got it?